# How do you host a SignalR Hub w/ Azure SignalR Serivce?

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I have developed a SignalR app locally. It runs the Hub class server-side.

I plan to deploy it using the Azure SignalR Service.  I see no way to host my Hub class.  How is this done?

(How do I run the Hub Class server-side?)

Comment: There's literally a Quickstarts section on the Azure SignalR Service documentation that has an example on using Azure SignalR service with ASP.NET Core: [Quickstart: Create a chat room with SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core)

Comment: The Hub Class is client-side, like most examples.  How do I host a Hub Class server-side?

Comment: The hub class is server side in the mentioned quick start.

Comment: The Hub doesn't run client side (read: in the browser of the visitor). It runs on the server side (read: the (IIS) back end) of the client application.

Comment: For others looking to **RUN A HUB CLASS SERVER-SIDE** - Azure SignalR Service doesn't support this out of box.  You need to add a web service just for your Hub Class - I ended up using an Azure Web App Service for the entire SignalR server project.  (you can offload SignalR traffic to the Azure SignalR Service then connect that to the web app service (Hub), documentation is lacking for this though.) --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Side Note - I thought my question was clear. _How do I run the Hub Class server-side?_ People were quick to point out headlines and examples that _clearly_ show that the Hub Class is NOT HOSTED ON THE SIGNALR SERVER. The Azure SignalR Service just acts as a relay so you can call the Hub Class methods (the Hub Class is NOT hosted on the Azure SignalR Service) So the comments are bunk and I hope people seeking a legit answer don't assume the up-voted comments are correct